# Largest protected forest (ancient woodland) in England?

Tags: uk, forests, england

I live in England and I like forests.  Where do I find the largest protected forest in England?

By protected I mean: no commercial logging (management logging is OK considering no forests without it exist in England), mining, or agriculture.  I can tolerate that hunting and fishing are still permitted.

I understand the English define ancient woodland as being [continuous since before 1600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_woodland), but for the sake of this question, I do not necessarily insist on it being ancient.

Comment: Do private/semi-private forests count like the Queen's land that commoners can't access?

Comment: @Erik Hmm, do you reckon the largest protected forest in England is private and closed to the public? If so, I'd be interested in knowing both the largest protected forest overall, and the largest protected forest with (possibly limited) public access (perhaps some public rights of way that visitors must not depart from).

Comment: I think the crown owns the largest forest reserves on the island, due to the old policy that the forests were the crown's property. Remember Robin Hood's transgression of poaching "the King's deer." I don't think the public has ready access to the crown's land because I vaguely remember something about a big forest/hunting preserve owned by the crown without public access. I could be wrong though. You might also want to specify if you are really restricting the area to England, or if you want to include the rest of Great Britain.

Comment: Logging, mining, and agriculture can all occur on legally protected land in England. So do you mean 'undisturbed' woodland? Logging for woodland occurs to one, keep out disease and two, to keep it classed as 'ancient' which is often a % value of the age of the trees, native tress etc.

Comment: @Erik, two points: "Forest" means both woodland and royal hunting ground in different senses. Generally there is reasonable access to large areas of Crown land, but not necessarily freedom to explore completely at will.

Comment: @Aravona I know that the Brits use the word National Park for places that include logging, mining, and agriculture.  But I believe that in nature reserves, they do not permit those.  That's why in my question, I specified what *I* mean by protected.  I believe that undisturbed forests do not exist in the UK, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @gerrit actually our local woods is protected ancient woodland and they do log in it. They've had to because of an ash tree disease in the area. Logging will occur in all woodland in the UK especially if it's protected. But it's not logging for wood to sell, it's logging for the general health of the forest/woods.

Comment: I actually have tweeted the people who'd know the answer to this, the woodland trust, but they've yet to respond.

Comment: @Aravona Ok.  Then I will settle for "no commercial logging".

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ancient_woods_in_England), the largest ancient woodland is the "[Windsor Great Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windsor_Great_Park)" (1777 Ha) :) However, this one doesn't really fit into your description, does it? The next biggest woodland is [King's and Baker's Wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King's_Wood,_Heath_and_Reach) (212 Ha).

Further information: http://www.protectedplanet.net/136567

[image]

Comment: Windsor great park is stunning. And I can safely say the best way to see it is by horse and carriage :)

Comment: @Aravona Didn't mean to say it's not! :) I just felt like Gerrit is searching for something else.

Comment: I'm not saying he isn't just saying it's stunning :)